# Report is not loading

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2012-datatools, reportserver

I have created one report with 4 parameters. one of the parameters having greater than 1000 item values.I have following issues

1. Reporting Services don't show data after selecting parameters
2. Reporting services displays blank page
3. Report is working fine in Visual Studio Preview mode, but not on Report Server web server

If I reduce the number of item values of parameter to 950 Report will work fine . Is there any idea to resolve the problems without reducing number of item values of parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be related to the `MaxHttpCollectionKeys` default value of `1000`

Add the following setting in the appSettings section of the Reporting Services config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="5000" />
</appSettings>
```